# Error bars on average for discrete limited values close to edge of range

Tags: discrete-data, measurement-error

Let's say I have discrete data that can only fall into a limited range - for example rating a product with a score from 1 to 10.
How would I go about assigning error bars to the average value of the data?
Staying with the example of a score from 1-10, let's say the average is 1.3, but there are a few outliers in the data at higher scores, so using something like the RMS would lead me to stating "the average is 1.3 +- 0.7". The lower end of this range does not make much sense, since the discrete values possible are limited to 1 -->  0.6 would not be a valid score.

On the other hand, if the distribution has more than 50% of the entries in a single bin (the bin with score 1 in the example), I also won't get very far by calculating an interquartile range and trying to use that to derive a range for error bars.

I thought there might be a way to assign poissonian errors to each bin and propagate those errors into the calculation of the average, but now I read a blog post on the topic (https://www.science20.com/quantum_diaries_survivor/those_deceiving_error_bars-85735), that's more or less convinced me that without an "underlying model" based on which I can do that (i.e. not knowing a priori what the average score is expected to be), that's also not the way to go.

I guess the error bars should be assymetric somehow, ending at the edges of the valid value range on the "limit side", but how do I best calculate the size of the errors in such a case?